# Which way is correct for setting CORS in new Spring?

Tags: java, spring, cors

I did not find the answer to my question on the Internet. What is the correct way to set up a global CORS for non-web application (json api only)?

I found org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration but i can't find where it use. Please, help me. I do not know what to do.

My spring version: 2.0.0.M4

Comment: If its not a web application you don't have a CORS issue.

Comment: To expand a bit on what @Deadron said, CORS is only used by browsers if your application is not going to be used by browsers CORS is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework).

Basically one way to do it is to have a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedOrigins("http://domain2.com")
        .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE")
            .allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3")
        .exposedHeaders("header1", "header2")
        .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

Or you can use a basic filter.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://domain1.com");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

There is also a `@CorsOrigin` annotation to configure per controller:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://domain2.com", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {...
```